# Filter XML collection based on child node data in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

I have following XML collection of students as shown below.

```
<stdXmlFormat version="1.0">
  <students>
    <field id="ClassId">CB0012</field>
    <field id="ClassName">CBSE-12</field>
    <student id="123">
      <field id="SFirstNm">Ram</field>
      <field id="SLastNm">Raju</field>
      <field id="RollNumber">001</field>
    </student>
    <student id="124">
      <field id="SFirstNm">Sita</field>
      <field id="SLastNm">M</field>
      <field id="RollNumber">002</field>
    </student>
    <collection id="StudentCollection">
      <record>
        <field id="StudentId">5094e0ef-c966-484d-9892-e62bd828e7cf</field>
        <field id="FirstName">Ram</field>
        <field id="LastName">Raju</field>
      </record>
      <record>
        <field id="StudentId">70a0350a-9556-46f6-b089-bebcc278b1c1</field>
        <field id="FirstName">Sita</field>
        <field id="LastName">M</field>
      </record>
    </collection>
    <collection id="AccountTransactions">
      <record>
        <field id="Id">62f4181a-5510-4522-a24a-7d3005f2a907</field>
        <field id="TransactionType">Fees</field>
        <field id="Balance">5000.00</field>
      </record>
      <record>
        <field id="Id">0958d991-c777-46b3-954c-3682ff735bfc</field>
        <field id="TransactionType">Fine</field>
        <field id="Balance">2000.00</field>
      </record>
      <record>
        <field id="Id">3aadb37d-d066-491f-8525-2e299ad8d88b</field>
        <field id="TransactionType">Fees</field>
        <field id="Balance">6000.00</field>
      </record>
    </collection>
    <collection id="StudentAccountTransactions">
      <record>
        <field id="Id">5e7d0c97-8759-4beb-a688-009e23f10590</field>
        <field id="StudentId">5094e0ef-c966-484d-9892-e62bd828e7cf</field>
        <field id="AccountTransactionsId">62f4181a-5510-4522-a24a-7d3005f2a907</field>
      </record>
      <record>
        <field id="Id">b22bf993-4dc2-49e6-879f-504ca4ec8424</field>
        <field id="StudentId">5094e0ef-c966-484d-9892-e62bd828e7cf</field>
        <field id="AccountTransactionsId">0958d991-c777-46b3-954c-3682ff735bfc</field>
      </record>
      <record>
        <field id="Id">44641d91-38bf-4e24-895c-20f92f390acf</field>
        <field id="StudentId">70a0350a-9556-46f6-b089-bebcc278b1c1</field>
        <field id="AccountTransactionsId">3aadb37d-d066-491f-8525-2e299ad8d88b</field>
      </record>
    </collection>
  </students>
</stdXmlFormat>
```

The **students** node is the parent node which consists of child nodes as  and collections (**StudentCollection**, **AccountTransactions** and **StudentAccountTransactions**).

```
<stdXmlFormat version="1.0">
  <students>
    <student></student>
    <collection id="StudentCollection"/>
    <collection id="AccountTransactions"/>   
    <collection id="StudentAccountTransactions"/>    
  </students>
</stdXmlFormat>
```

**students** node is containing all the student details such  first name,last name, roll number etc(this was an old collection with more information.some attributes i have removed for better reading and understanding)

And same information is available in the new collection ***StudentCollection*** but with less data.this collection is having **StudentId** (a unique guid used for identifying the student in other collections). the only relation with ***students*** and ***StudentCollection*** is the student first name and last name.

The ***AccountTransactions*** is the collection which holds id (a unique guid for identifying each transactions) and other transaction details. The id in this collection used as AccountTransactionsId in the ***StudentAccountTransactions*** collection.

The final collection ***StudentAccountTransactions*** which holds the studentid (from StudentCollection) and AccountTransactionsId (from AccountTransactions collection).

So from this list i need to get the details of the students and pass it to DB TEAM for saving to database.They are ready with table structure as shown below

[image: StudentTranssactionTable]

Basically i need to fetch the SFirstNm,SLastNm,RollNumber( from student), StudentId,AccountTransactionsId and StudentAccountTransactionsId from this collection.

I have tried to get the data using XMLdocument and Xdocument but nothing worked

```
string xpath = @"/stdXmlFormat/students/students/field";
XmlNodeList nodeListstudent = root.SelectNodes(xpath);
foreach (XmlNode item in nodeListstudent )
            {
                string SID = item.Attributes["id"].Value;
                string sFirstNm, sLastNm = string.Empty;
                foreach (XmlNode childNodes in item .ChildNodes)
                {                       
                    string NodeName = childNodes.Attributes["id"].Value;
                    string NodeValue = childNodes.InnerText;

                    if (NodeName == "sFirstNm")
                    {
                        sFirstNm= NodeValue;
                    }
                    if (NodeName == "aBLastNm")
                    {
                        sLastNm = NodeValue;
                    }                        
                }
                
            }
```

From this i was able to get the student first name and last names etc but how i can fetch the student id from **StudentCollection** using first name and last name? i am really stuck here please help. with that studentid i need to get other details such as AccountTransactionsId and StudentAccountTransactionsId.

I tried to filter the studentid collections using following way for testing purpose but not worked.

```
XmlNodeList nodes = jsonXmlDocument.SelectNodes("//stdXmlFormat/students/collection/record/field[@id='5094e0ef-c966-484d-9892-e62bd828e7cf']");
```

Please help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {

        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("StudentId", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("SFirstNm", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("SLastNm", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("RollNumber", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("AccountTransaction", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("StudentAccountTransaction", typeof(string));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement xStudents = doc.Descendants("students").FirstOrDefault();
            var students = xStudents.Elements("student")
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
                    sFName = (string)x.Elements("field").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("id") == "SFirstNm").FirstOrDefault(),
                    sLName = (string)x.Elements("field").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("id") == "SLastNm").FirstOrDefault(),
                    rollNumber = (string)x.Elements("field").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("id") == "RollNumber").FirstOrDefault(),
                }).ToList();

            XElement xStudentCollection = doc.Descendants("collection").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == "StudentCollection").FirstOrDefault();

            var studentCollection = xStudentCollection.Elements("record")
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    sId = (string)x.Elements("field").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("id") == "StudentId").FirstOrDefault(),
                    sFName = (string)x.Elements("field").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("id") == "FirstName").FirstOrDefault(),
                    sLName = (string)x.Elements("field").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("id") == "LastName").FirstOrDefault(),
                }).ToList();

            XElement xAccountTransactions = doc.Descendants("collection").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == "AccountTransactions").FirstOrDefault();

            var accountTransactions = xAccountTransactions.Elements("record")
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    tId = (string)x.Elements("field").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("id") == "Id").FirstOrDefault(),
                    type = (string)x.Elements("field").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("id") == "TransactionType").FirstOrDefault(),
                    balanse = (decimal)x.Elements("field").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("id") == "Balance").FirstOrDefault(),
                }).ToList();

            XElement xStudentAccountTransactions = doc.Descendants("collection").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == "StudentAccountTransactions").FirstOrDefault();

            var studentAccountTransactions = xStudentAccountTransactions.Elements("record")
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    satId = (string)x.Elements("field").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("id") == "Id").FirstOrDefault(),
                    sId = (string)x.Elements("field").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("id") == "StudentId").FirstOrDefault(),
                    tId = (string)x.Elements("field").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("id") == "AccountTransactionsId").FirstOrDefault(),
                }).ToList();

            var studentRoll = students.Select(s => studentCollection.Where(sc => (s.sFName == sc.sFName) && (s.sLName == sc.sLName))
                .Select(x => new { fName = s.sFName, lName = s.sLName, roll = s.rollNumber, sId = x.sId }).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

            var tranactions = accountTransactions.Select(at => studentAccountTransactions.Where(act => at.tId == act.tId)
                .Select(x => new { tId = x.tId, type = at.type, balance = at.balanse, satId = x.satId }).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

            var results = (from sat in studentAccountTransactions
                           join tr in tranactions on sat.tId equals tr.tId
                           join  sr in studentRoll on sat.sId equals sr.sId
                           select new { sr = sr, tr = tr, sat = sat })
                           .ToList();
            foreach(var r in results)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[]
                {
                    r.sr.sId,
                    r.sr.fName,
                    r.sr.lName,
                    r.sr.roll,
                    r.tr.tId,
                    r.sat.satId
                });
            }    
           
        }

    }
 
 
}
```

Comment: I updated the code and got everything working.